# C11 compiler conformance comparison

Tags: c, c11, standards-compliance

Was there any site that compares the current C11 standard conformance/support between implementation/compilers? (gcc, clang, intel, open64, pelles)

Comment: A pedantic reading of the standard suggests that it is impossible to create a compliant implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no general site (this is a good time to start one :).  However, most projects maintain their own list:

<strike>http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html (clang)</strike> http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#c

http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status (gcc)

Comment: @Kokizzu you are correct.  http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#c is the closest I find on the Clang site